# XUI toggleClass error

Tags: javascript, xui

I have a input that I press then this event is called:

```
document.getElementById("nearest").addEventListener('click', function(){
    x$("#popup").toggleClass('hide');
}, false);
```

then I get this error in console:

```
x$("#popup").toggleClass is not a function
[Break On This Error] x$("#popup").toggleClass('hide');
```

This is the div and the input element

```
<div id="popup" class="hide"></div>
<input id="nearest" type="image" name="nearest">
```

Comment: XUI works, its just this that does not work

Answer (score 0):

The below code seems to work as expected—it toggles the background color from red to blue (tested in FireFox 8.0 and Chrome 17.0.942.0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #popup{
            position:relative;
            height:100px;
            width:100px;
            margin:10px;
            background-color:red;
       }
        .hide{
            background-color:blue !important;
        }
    </style>


    <script type="application/javascript" src="http://xuijs.com/downloads/xui-2.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript">
        x$.ready(function() { 
            document.getElementById('nearest').addEventListener('click', function(){
                x$("#popup").toggleClass('hide');
            }, false);
        });
    </script> 
</head>
<body>
    <div id="popup" class="hide"></div>
    <input id="nearest" type="image" name="nearest" />
</body>
</html>
```

Just to confirm, I assume the `document.getElementId()` you originally used was part of a function or enclosed in some onLoad script? In the working example I used XUIs `ready()` function to make sure the DOM had loaded.

It's also worth noting that the below code is equivalent, since you're using XUI anyway:

```
x$.ready(function() { 
    x$('#nearest').click(function(){
        x$("#popup").toggleClass('hide');
    });
});
```